# Drupal: last core version update. Risky, if I don't update it?

Tags: drupal

I did several websites with Drupal, and now the core is updated and I cannot come back to my customers to update previous installation. I was wondering how risky is to not update drupal core to the last version and how web developers should deal with websites management.

ps. My customers do not have any computer skills.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The openness of open source means that it is easy to know what an upgrade has fixed. It also means that a hacker could just look at the release notes and do a `diff` between the previous and current version to spot the vulnerabilities in the previous version.

If you have a good relationship with your clients I would explain the need for an upgrade and see if they want to pay you for it, as their sites are vulnerable to anyone determined enough to look at the release notes and do a little digging.

Comment: can a hacker easily find out the installed drupal version ?

Comment: I don't think they can tell from reading the HTML. If I were a sneaky hacker-man, I would just assume that for a few days-weeks after a new core release, most sites would not be updated yet. 
Also, any vulnerabilities found and fixed by a new release will probably still exist in an older release. For example, if there is an XSS vulnerability fixed by 6.10, then it probably exists in all 6.x versions before 6.10 as well.

Comment: @Patrick, relatively. Most people don't delete out the text files in the root. CHANGELOG.txt has all the info anyone needs.

Comment: isn't CHANGELOG.txt private ? I mean, how can they access to it ? Just for curiosity.

Comment: CHANGELOG.txt is hidden by Drupal's .htaccess file, and should be protected by permissions on your server as well.
If they can access your CHANGELOG.txt file then you have bigger problems then someone knowing what version of Drupal you are running.

Answer (score 2):

Here are [release notes](http://drupal.org/node/732000). Answer on your question lies inside.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the core is very Important, it solves some security risks and brings new features.